# Issue adding content from PHP file to Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

so here's the thing, I'm not sure if my database is connecting successfully or not, and if it is then my input query isn't working. Here is what I have. I'm sure my mistake is fairly obvious and I'm likely to kick myself but please help.

HTML:

```
<form action="adduser.php" method="post">
    <label>Create Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br>
    <label>Create Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
    <label>Confirm Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
    <label>Select Gender</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male</button>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</button><br>
    <label>Click submit to continue</label><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php
$username = "********";
$password = "***********";
$db = "localhost";
$dbconn = mysql_connect($db, $username, $password);
    if (!$dbconn){
        die ("Connection failure!");
    }

    return "Connection Successful.";

    mysql_select_db("who_do_it_db", $dbconn);
?>
```

adduser.php:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$uName = $_POST['username'];
$pWord = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Gender) VALUES ("$uName","$pWord","$gender");';
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: 1. `$post` is going to not echo the user table, you need `mysql_fetch_assoc` in a loop

Comment: 2. Use `mysqli_*` as `mysql_*` functions are depreciated

Comment: 3. Your code is open to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp SQL Injection

Comment: Also, make sure you escape the data, now you're open for sql injection.

Comment: Please, please stop using mysql_*.  I recommend reading this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: Use `echo mysql_error();` after your query to find the problem.

Comment: Is that `return "Connection Successful."` before you actually select your database really what you want to do?

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php and the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return` in the included file. Therefore the scripts finishes there and never reaches any command after the `include` in `adduser.php`